# Work javascript according to checkbox's state

Tags: javascript, html

I have a checkbox that toggle the div and i register the choice to localstore and get it back

But the thing that i can't do is javascript that toggles the div won't see that checkbox's option it's needs to toggle it twice

index.html

```
<div id="siit" class="sit"></div>

Clock?: <br>
        <label class="switch">
          <input id="tetik" type="checkbox">
          <span class="slider round"></span>
        </label>
```

saat.js

```
function basla() {
  var today = new Date();
  var h = today.getHours();
  var m = today.getMinutes();
  var s = today.getSeconds();
  h = checkTime(h);
  m = checkTime(m);
  s = checkTime(s);
  document.getElementById('siit').innerHTML =
  h + ":" + m + ":" + s;
  var t = setTimeout(basla, 500);
}
function checkTime(i) {
  if (i < 10) {i = "0" + i};  // add zero in front of numbers < 10
  return i;
};
```

Here is the codepen: https://codepen.io/Etka/pen/BvGKWV

I want this: when user choose to show the clock and leave, when user comes back the javascript will check the checkbox if it's checked will show the clock

Comment: Why do you have duplicate functions in your codepen?

Comment: This not the real code i copy paste the most necessary one so mistakes can be happen, i fix it thank you by the way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When checking the selected state and check the checkbox, also make the clock visible.

```
// Set the selected state
    if (isSaved === "true") {
      checkbox.checked = true;
      $("#siit").show();
    }
```

Comment: Thank you! This fixes my problem

Answer (score 0):

Change the css `display` property of the clock div element `#siit` to `"block"` inside your `init()` function if the checkbox is saved in LocalStorage by changing this:

```
if (isSaved === "true") {
  checkbox.checked = true;
}
```

To this:

```
if (isSaved === "true") {
  checkbox.checked = true;
  document.getElementById("siit").style.display = "block";
}
```

Here is a CodePen with the above modified code that I forked from your original one: https://codepen.io/andrewl64/pen/LMXNgj?editors=0010

Comment: Thank you for helping me, this is one of the answer but when i apply this to more connected div it not properly worked but my problem solved and i got this too for my future projects thank you again!

Comment: Glad I could help Etka. Cheers.